# What is best Primary action UX writing for this scenario?

Tags: forms, buttons, ux-writing

What do you think about UX writing of primary action?  should be named as just `Add` or `Add holidays`. For me `Add` doesn't give clues to the user about what going to add.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it's always a better idea to give more context for buttons, unless you start putting paragraphs of text as their labels - they still need to stay [scannable](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-web-users-scan-instead-reading/). Two to three words should be fine.

The argument in your case could be:

> The label for the whole form is "Add holidays", so why would we duplicate the label on the button?

But if we consider that users would probably spend more than a second in this form, defining all the holidays, using a more context-aware label could be useful - less chance of users getting confused without any real downsides.

For more tips, check these articles:

- https://medium.com/sainsburys-customer-experience/a-quick-guide-to-writing-better-button-labels-69daecff3497
- https://uxmovement.com/buttons/5-rules-for-choosing-the-right-words-on-button-labels/

P.S. On an unrelated note, I noticed that the inputs for the holiday are in the order Name - Date, but added values are the other way around: Date - Name. It's usually a good idea to use the same order in both cases - this way you'll lower the unnecessary cognitive load.

Comment: Thank you! P.S. Thank for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Giving more context is always better. It creates a consistent and lighter cognitive load if the main CTA and the page title are connected. Especially given there's enough space. I would suggest adding the count as well (how many holidays will be added) to give the user more confirmation.